# PHP intval() behaviour?

Tags: php, string, casting, integer

This sounds to strange to me:

```
$test_1 = 'string';
$test_2 = '0';

var_dump(intval($test_1)); // Output: int 0
var_dump(intval($test_2)); // Output: int 0

$can_cast = intval($test_2) ? 'sure' : 'nope'; // Wrong!!!
```

So with a `string` to `int` conversion `intval` returns **0**. Fine, but it returns **0** also when the string actually can be casted to zero (because *is* zero) thus valid.

How can one can distinguish between both (allows '0' as string and deny 'string')?

**EDIT**: ok let me say i know i can use `is_numeric`. `But is_numeric('2.3')` returns `true`, so it can't help. And:

```
$test = '0';
var_dump(is_numeric($test) && intval($test)); // Fail!!!
```

Comment: `is_numeric()` might be right for you?

Comment: What about `'0.0'`,  `'0.1'` or `'0foo'`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario i've edited the question, you've got the point.

Comment: What do you mean by "Fail!!!" for the is_numeric example? It's false as expected, right?

Comment: intval is a conversion, not check, so it always returns an integer. Thus, it is impossible to know from intval if the argument was integer or not - it's not meant for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) check before you cast (if you want only positive numbers). Alternatively you could do an integer validation using [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) and [`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). The integer validation will also check integer semantics, i.e. it will ensure that the integer is within the allowed range. You can also customize it for your needs through several options.